# Object that is not null showing as null inside of my method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, console-application

*** EDIT *** :: I found the issue while gathering the actual code.

I am working with C# in Visual Studio 2015

I am having trouble passing a class object that has a field of type class object. I created two simple classes, a class A & class B, and class A has a field in it of type class B. After creating an instance of class A and then setting its field of type class B to a new instance of class B it seems to work fine. But then when I pass the instance of class A into a method the field of type class B shows as Null. I can write the values of all the class B fields and they show the correct values during debug before heading into a method, but when passing my class A object into a method it throws the NullReferenceException and tells me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." All other fields in my class A object work fine; the field of type class B is the only one that does this.

When I copy/pasted the method to a new solution and trimmed/added to get rid of all the errors it worked fine. So, I am not sure why my program keeps failing in this way.

Any suggestions?

```
class Program
{

    // Start of the program
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Instantiate the player
        Player player = new Player() { playerWeapon = new Weapon() };

        showPlayerStats(player);
    }

    // Method shows the player's stats
    static void showPlayerStats(Player player)

    {
        Console.WriteLine(" ******** Player Statistics ********");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(" Player Name:".PadRight(16) + player.playerName);
        Console.WriteLine(" Player Gender:".PadRight(16) + player.playerGender);
        Console.WriteLine(" Player Race:".PadRight(16) + player.playerRace);
        Console.WriteLine(" Player Class:".PadRight(16) + player.playerClass);
        Console.WriteLine(" Player Health:".PadRight(16) + player.playerHealth + "/" + player.playerMaxHealth);
        Console.WriteLine(" Player EXP:".PadRight(16) + player.playerEXP);
        Console.WriteLine(" Player Gold:".PadRight(16) + player.playerMoney);
        Console.WriteLine(" Player Weapon:".PadRight(16) + player.playerWeapon.name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // Create player with random attributes
    static Player RandomPlayer()
    {
        Player player = new Player(); //<<== This is where I goofed
        return player;
    }
}
class Player
{
    public string playerName = "Name";
    public string playerGender = "Gender";
    public string playerRace = "Race";
    public string playerClass = "Class";
    public int playerHealth = 100;
    public int playerEXP = 0;
    public int playerMaxHealth = 100;
    public int playerMoney = 50;
    public double playerOneHanded = 1;
    public double playerTwoHanded = 1;
    public double playerRanged = 1;
    public double playerMagic = 1;
    public Weapon playerWeapon;
}

class Weapon
{
    public string name = "Knife";
    public int damage = 6;
    public string type = "One";
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code that works. Please post a [mcve] of the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: You need to post your real code before this question gets enough votes to be closed.

Comment: Please share the code that **doesn't** work. We can't help you without seeing it.

Comment: Now you've edited in a comment saying your working code doesn't work (it does work though), very odd!

Comment: My guess is that you've got a local variable hiding a field. But until you can post code that demonstrates the problem, it'll be hard to say for sure.

Comment: Well, I thought that it would be too much to post the bits in action, it's part of a larger console program, so I made a simple example. I will NOT make that mistake again. Thank you.and when I went back through to piece together what was

Comment: - the problem I found that I was running through a Random method to create a random character and THAT method was returning a new instance of Player, which had no value for weapon. I answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem when I went back through the code to gather the actual snippets. I was using the random character creation process while testing the game and I had neglected to put a Weapon to the Player.playerWeapon field after the the method that returned a player, thus using the new instance of Player object with a Null field. Thanks for the assistance.